# footer overlap content when break page. how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, css

When I print html, the content is overwritten by the footer and I print it on firefox 42

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rompf.png)


 this is my css

```html
@media print {
    table {
        page-break-inside:auto
    }
    tr {
        page-break-inside:avoid;
        page-break-after:auto;
    }
    .header-TQ {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin-top: -15px;
    }
    .content-TQ {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: -5px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        line-height: 1.42857 !important;
        position: relative;
        top: 65px;
  }
```

Comment: Could you please include your HTML in the question and the snippet. Also include more of the CSS, if applicable. This will help me and the community assist you better.

Comment: Looks like your footer has a fixed position and is overlapping the content, but like @MikeHermary said, it's hard to tell without the actual code.